# MVC disable submit button on @Html.DropdownList value select

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How to disable submit button on dropdownlist  selected value?

View:

```
 @Html.Label("Select Department :")
 @Html.DropDownList("GroupId", String.Empty )
 <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Get Report</button>
```

Controller:

```
ViewBag.GroupId = new SelectList(db.NGAC_GROUP, "ID", "Name");
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#GroupId').on('input change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "REGULAR") {
            $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Tried other codes but none seem to work. Thanks

Comment: What if any errors are you getting in the browser console? (and why would you want to disable the submit button anyway?)

Comment: And id the `ID` property if `NGAC_GROUP` really a `string` (and one of them has a value of "REGULAR")?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I get no errors. It runs smoothly but not working

Comment: @StephenMuecke I get the ID value of the dropdownlist value but only posting the name of the ID value in the view

Comment: The add a `console.log($(this).val());` and inspect the result (its hard to imagine that your `ID` property has a value such as `"REGULAR"`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke the value was taken from the database linked by the model. The group id of was '1' while the name was 'REGULAR'. I wanted to disable the button due to roles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167065/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-john-clarence-castro).

Answer (score 0):

try this code hope it will help you to disable button

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#GroupId').on('input change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "REGULAR") {
        $('#submit').attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else {
        $('#submit').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

});

Comment: `.attr("disabled", true);` is the same as `.prop('disabled', true);` except the 2nd is the recommended approach. This has nothing to do with the question